# Magento 2 Customer login and forgot Password using Rest API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, webapi

I need **customer login and customer forgot password using Magento 2 API**. Can you please help me. I was search but not getting any code from google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the API, you should read more:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html
- http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/

For example, this below code will return the customer info:

```
<?php

$userData = ["username" => "customeruser@gmail.com", "password" => "123456"];
$ch = curl_init("http://magen2.loc/rest/V1/integration/customer/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);

//Get customer info
$ch = curl_init("http://magen2.loc/rest/V1/customers/me");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); // Get method
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

For the customer forgot password:

```
$emailcontent = [
    "email"=> "test@gmail.com",
    "template" => "email_reset", // Using template email reset
    "websiteId" => 1
];



$ch = curl_init("http://magen2.loc/rest/V1/customers/password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); // Put method
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($emailcontent));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks As of now login is perfect working. But in forgot password i got some error. You can see below error.

 Invalid type for value: "password". Expected Type: "int".

can you please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: @KartikAsodariya you used the second code lines?

Comment: I was use both code and login working fine but getting some issues with forgot password which you can see above comment

Comment: @KartikAsodariya strange, I have checked, my code lines are working fine. Which is your Magento version?

Comment: Magento ver. 2.1.3

Comment: Try with this: https://gist.github.com/mrkhoa99/66a39fdc46958c721bb5160864d27ad9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53163/discussion-between-kartik-asodariya-and-khoa-truongdinh).

Comment: Hello. What `token` in forgot password?

Answer (score 0):

$email = $retorno['cliente']['email'];

```
$emailcontent = [
    "email"=> $email,
    "template" => AccountManagement::EMAIL_RESET, // Using template email reset
    "websiteId" => 1
];  

$ch = curl_init($url."rest/V1/customers/password");
Report($url."rest/V1/customers/password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); // Put method
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($emailcontent));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$customer   = $obj->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->setStore($store)->loadByEmail($email);
```